# Magento Enterprise returns 404 error: Page not found on nginx, CentOS

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, nginx, centos

I have some big issue with running magento on nginx, php-fpm.

http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8108/magento4042.png

I was trying for 3 days to solve it. I can't open any page (including home page).

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #
    fastcgi_send_timeout 1800;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 1800;
}
```

And here is my default.conf

```
server {
  root     /var/www/;
  index    index.php;
  server_name   magento.example.com;
  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
  }
  location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Cache is disabled. Url_rewrites to. Please tell me, how to debug it?

Comment: I delete fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default; because I don't have default store, and now it works.

Comment: Be careful about changing the default store's code: some Magento code has it hard-coded in it, so by doing that you might break some standard functionality.